# HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap for single writer / single reader scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

Here are the details.

1. One thread writes to the map, another thread reads from it.
2. A key once inserted is never updated.
3. If consumer thread doesn't find the value in the map, it can compute the value itself. It won't find 1% of the values, as they would not have been computed by the producer thread.
4. When the consumer asks for a value, it should get it as fast as possible.

Will `HashMap` without synchronization work in this case? Or I will have to use `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: No, and yes. A HashMap is not thread safe. Writing and reading from it concurrently is thus not safe.

Comment: **Of course** the details are in the description. Downvote for stupid title.

Comment: Since your "reader" can also compute a value, you could have it put this value into the map with `computeIfAbsent`

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to read and write from a map from multiple threads concurrently, you need `ConcurrentHashMap`. `HashMap` will not do, because an attempt to execute a `get` concurrently with a `put` may lead to incorrect behavior.

If the writing thread finishes before the reading thread starts, you could use regular `HashMap`.

Comment: There are alternatives​ to `ConcurrentHashMap`, though not necessarily better ones. You pick the one most suited to the use case.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you need a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

The slightly longer explanation is that there are two reasons for this. Firstly, a simple `HashMap` risks reader and writer threads working on the same internal data of the `HashMap` at the same time. For a `HashMap` to maintain its correctness it obviously has to update multiple internal properties in a way that has to appear to happen as a single operation to any client. Allowing a reader to query the `HashMap` while a writer is busy modifying these properties can lead to unexpected behaviour.

The second point is that the visibility of changes made by one thread are not available in a predictable manner to other threads without the use of Java's concurrent support mechanisms. So, even if a writer finished before a reader queries the `HashMap` there is no guarantee the reader would see the data as the writer left it - a `ConcurrentHashMap` takes care of this problem.

The first point is something which is more likely on single processor machines where a writer thread may complete part of its work of inserting a new value and then yield while a reader thread reads from the partially updated map. The second point is more of an issue on multi-core machines where each core will have its own version of shared memory which only gets synchronised with other cores predictably if you use concurrency mechanisms.

Comment: "Allowing a reader to query the HashMap while a writer is busy modifying these properties can lead to unexpected behaviour." - Do you have a plausible scenario in mind? Plausible in the sense that the reader doesn't go out of its way to detect race conditions.

Comment: Well, the most obvious operation would be when the HashMap needs to grow capacity. If a reader began a query by getting a reference to the internal table then yielded to a writer which resized and rebuilt the table, then the reader would resume with a reference to a table which had been completely discarded by the HashMap.

Comment: Good point about resizes. While I'm not worried about reading the old table (although that might cause the reader to miss old entries in certain implementations as well), if the writer decides to change the table reference before it's done writing to it, the reader will likely miss data.  Good to realize when I'm writing a 1W1R lock-free hashmap.

Comment: If a key-value pair is never updated once inserted, [as it happens to be the case with me], the resize and old reference should not be an issue. Am I correct?

Comment: No - consider that a key may belong in one hash bucket before a resize operation and in a different one afterwards. Also, you need to consider the (perhaps unlikely) situation that hash buckets with a lot of collisions may get re-configured as a tree structure (in Java 8). This is the sort of stuff you need to think about if you don't use Java's concurrency mechanisms.

Comment: Just though of one more issue to consider which is that of contracts. Even if your code worked with the current `HashMap` you cannot guarantee your code will work with `HashMap` in the next release of Java because it doesn't offer any thread safe guarantees and its implementation can (and probably will) change. `ConcurrentHashMap` can be guaranteed to work into the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am responding as per your question.

You should use `ConcurrentHashMap` because it is thread-safe whereas `HashMap` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the reader and writer are different threads, then you do need a thread-safe data structure.  That precludes using a bare (i.e. unsynchronized) `HashMap`.

I can think of three alternatives.

- A `HashMap` with external synchronization.  (This would need to be implemented carefully.)
- Wrap a `HashMap` (or another `Map` class) using `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)`.  This will work if the reader and writer are just doing gets and puts.  However, if either need to iterate the map there will be problems.
- Use `ConcurrentHashMap`.  The only slight concern is that `ConcurrentHashMap`s support for high contention might be a bit costly in a low contention use-case.

Certainly, `ConcurrentHashMap` is the simplest alternative.

Comment: It's worth noting also that the performance of `ConcurrentHashMap` is potentially much better. Using the `Collections.synchronizedMap()` call means that only a single thread can access the map at once while `ConcurrentHashMap` allows concurrent access, particularly when different threads are working on different keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. The source code does in fact look like you can get away with it. It doesn't look like there can be any loops in abandoned nodes causing your thread to get stuck or anything. Your worst case scenario seems to be that you're not seeing values that are actually there during resize or treeify operations. But you're going to have to compute 1% of the values in the reading thread anyway, so this probably won't bother you.

But we need to think a little harder here. Memory reordering can give you references to *uninitialized* objects or partially initialized objects.

I believe that a partially initialized `Node` can even give you false positives. If the `Node` comes from a location in memory which was previously also holding a `Node`, it should be possible to see a wrong key-value pair if you're seeing one of them from the concurrent put and one of them from before the garbage collection.

This is insanely unlikely and memory reordering should probably only give you more false negatives, but I'd stay away from it unless you have a very fast way of validating the value.